# Promises doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I'm starting to learn Promises in JS.
 i wrote a function, that animates a displaying text on screen:

```
function Animal(string) {
    var a = ''; //variable which will be entered character by character string
    var i= 0;//Letter counter
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    $('body').scrollTop($('body').append(p).height());

    Anima();
    function Anima() {//Function of Animation   
        a+=string[i];
        i++;
        $('p').last().text(a);
        var timer = setTimeout(Anima, 100);
        if(i==string.length){
            clearTimeout(timer);
        };
    };
};
```

I wrote it by using callbacks and displaying of three text strings views like:

```
Animal('... ', () =>{                                                   //1
    Animal('---Hello! CONSOLE v 1.0.1 is working!---', () =>{           //2
        Animal('STRING1', () =>{                                    //3                                     
            Animal('STriNG2', () => {                               //4
                Animal('STRING 3', () => {return;})}
        )}
    })
})
});
```

Today i started to learn Promices. PLease, tell me, why it isn't working?

```
var Testobj = [
    '1rst string',
    '2ond string',
    '3rd string',
    '4th string'
];

var chain = Promise.resolve();

Testobj.forEach(function(txt) {
  chain = chain
    .then(Animal(txt));
});
```

PS
And how to fix it?:)

Comment: i don't see any promises other than a resolved one

Comment: All I see is major abuse of what a Promise object can do, and nothing indicating a Promise being used properly.

Answer (score 2):

Two issues:

- The Animal function should return a promise to ensure that the `then` callbacks will be called only when the previous promise in the chain is resolved.
- You call *Animal* directly when providing the argument to `then`. Instead, you should pass the function reference.

Here is the fixed code:

```js
function Animal(string) {
    var a = ''; //variable which will be entered character by character string
    var i= 0;//Letter counter
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    $('body').scrollTop($('body').append(p).height());
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        Anima();
        function Anima() {//Function of Animation   
            a+=string[i];
            i++;
            $('p').last().text(a);
            var timer = setTimeout(Anima, 100);
            if(i==string.length){
                clearTimeout(timer);
                resolve();
            };
        };
    });
};        

var Testobj = [
    '1rst string',
    '2ond string',
    '3rd string',
    '4th string'
];

var chain = Promise.resolve();

Testobj.forEach(function(txt) {
  chain = chain.then(Animal.bind(null,txt));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Although this works, the chaining you do in the loop is really a good candidate for using `reduce`, which makes it more *functional programming* code:

```
Testobj.reduce(function(chain, txt) {
    return chain.then(Animal.bind(null,txt));
}, Promise.resolve());
```

Comment: wow! Yeah. Thanks, thanks, thanks! But why we must use `.bind` on the `Animal()` function?

Comment: don't use `forEach` like that, better use `reduce`: `var chain = Testobj.reduce((chain, txt) => chain.then(Animal.bind(null,txt), Promise.resolve());` *(the intention is neither the one-liner, nor the fat-arrow, but to avoid creating a variable and mutating it)*

Comment: @mayst, because `then()` doesn't expect the Promise that `Animal(txt)` creates but a function that returns some value. By binding `txt` to `Animal`, we're passing a function to `then`. You could also write `chain.then( () => Animal(txt) )` or `chain.then(function(){ return Animal(txt) })` instead.

Comment: `bind` makes sure that the argument *txt* is passed, but it does not *call* the function on the spot, instead it passes the function

Comment: *"don't use `forEach` like that"* is maybe too strongly put, but indeed `reduce` is the ideal method for this kind of chaining. Added it to my answer in ES5 syntax.

Comment: Thank u guys! U helped me a lot!